# What happens if I Monitor.Enter conditionally while another thread is in the critical section without a lock?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I'm attempting to reimplement functionality from a system class (`Lazy<T>`) and I found this unusual bit of code.  I get the basic idea. The first thread to try for a value performs the calculations. Any threads that try while that's happening get locked at the gate, wait until release, and then go get the cached value.  Any later calls notice the sentinel value and don't bother with the locks any more.

```
bool lockWasTaken = false;
var obj = Volatile.Read<object>(ref this._locker);
object returnValue = null;

try
{
    if (obj != SENTINEL_VALUE)
    {
        Monitor.Enter(obj, ref lockWasTaken);
    }

    if (this.cachedValue != null) // always true after code has run once
    {
        returnValue = this.cachedValue;
    }
    else //only happens on the first thread to lock and enter
    {
        returnValue = SomeCalculations();
        this.cachedValue = returnValue;
        Volatile.Write<object>(ref this._locker, SENTINEL_VALUE);
    }
    return returnValue
}
finally
{
    if (lockWasTaken)
    {
        Monitor.Exit(obj); 
    }
}
```

But let's say, after a change in the code, that another method resets the `this._locker` to it's original value and then goes in to lock and recalculate the cached value.  While it does this, another thread happened to be picking up the cached value, so it's inside the locked section, but without a lock.  What happens?  Does it just execute normally while the thread with the lock also goes in parallel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> While it does this, another thread happened to be picking up the cached value, so it's inside the locked section, but without a lock. What happens? Does it just execute normally while the thread with the lock also goes in parallel?

Yes, it'll just execute normally.

That being said, this code appears like it could be removed entirely by using [`Lazy<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  The `Lazy<T>` class provides a thread safe way to handle lazy instantiation of data, which appears to be the goal of this code.

Basically, the entire code could be replaced by:

```
// Have a field like the following:
Lazy<object> cachedValue = new Lazy<object>(() => SomeCalculations());

// Code then becomes:
return cachedValue.Value;
```

Comment: It actually is the code from the `Lazy<T>` class. I was reimplementing it to make a version that can be reset.  There's fairly simple ways around that using the existing Lazy class, but I thought it'd be fun, and a good way to experiment with multithreaded code.